# How to set default date time as system date time in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I am trying to set my columns default date time to system datetime. 
It shows me an error

> Invalid default value for
>   'InsertionDate'

```
alter table `vts`.`tblpickpoint` 
  add column `InsertionDate` 
      datetime DEFAULT 'Now()' NULL after `PickPointLatLong`
```

Comment: Even if you could use a function as default value (you cannot) you aren't providing a function: `'Now()'` is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for a column in mysql cannot be the result of a function.

The one exception is the current_timestamp as astander points out.

Your statement should be

```
alter table `vts`.`tblpickpoint` 
  add column `InsertionDate` TIMESTAMP 
             DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to init and update the value on every change, use this:

```
alter table `vts`.`tblpickpoint` 
  add column `InsertionDate` 
       TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  after `PickPointLatLong`
```

If you only want the creation time, use this:

```
alter table `vts`.`tblpickpoint` 
  add column `InsertionDate` 
       TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  after `PickPointLatLong`
```